# Difference between generator and the sigma algebra generated by this generator

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is any set and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^X $. By definition, I have learnt that $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{F} $. I am trying to understand the difference between $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $ and $\mathcal{F} $.

With specific example, suppose $\mathcal{F} = \{ f(A) : A \in \mathcal{G} \} $ where $\mathcal{G} $ is a $\sigma$-algebra. I am trying to understand $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $ and $f$ is a real-valued function defined on $X$. Obviously, $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $ contains all the $f(A) $ for $A \in \mathcal{G} $. What else does it contain? Because we don't have $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) = \mathcal{F} $.

Comment: What does $f$ refer to?

Comment: ops, sorry I didnt define it. Lets say it is just any function.

Comment: can we assume you mean a function $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (as opposed to some function on $2^X$)?

Comment: ok, sure, lets assume that.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\sigma(\mathcal F)=\mathcal F$. Otherwise $\mathcal F$ is a proper subset of $\sigma(\mathcal F)$.

For your example, $\mathcal F$ need not be a $\sigma$-algebra. Take for instance $X = \{a\}$ and $f(a)=0$. Then $$\mathcal F=\{f(\varnothing), f(\{a\})\}= \{\varnothing, \{0\}\},$$
whereas
$$\sigma(\mathcal F) = \{\varnothing, \{0\}, \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}, \mathbb R\}.$$

Comment: Question, then, in general, what is the stuff that is in $\sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $ but not in $\mathcal{F} $ ?

Comment: Essentially, the elements of $2^X$ that can be produced by countably many set operations (union, intersection, and complement) from the sets in $\mathcal F $. There isn't a concise way to answer this question in general. For example, there is no generic description of a Borel set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, for example, in the real line $\Bbb R$: $${\frak U }= \{ \left]a,b\right[ \mid a,b \in \Bbb R, \,a<b\}.$$ Then $[0,1] \in \sigma(\frak U)$ but $[0,1] \not\in \frak U$. In general, the sigma-algebra itself is way bigger than its generator.

The sigma-algebra contains countable unions of elements of the generator, as well as countable intersections, countable unions of countable intersections, etc.

In the specific example above (or in general, about the sigma-algebra generated by the topology of a topological space), we call any set who is a countable union of open sets a $G_\delta$ set. We call any set who is a countable intersection of closed sets a $F_\sigma$ set.

We go on: any countable intersection of $F_\sigma$s we call a $F_{\sigma \delta}$ set, any countable union of $G_\delta$s we call a $G_{\delta\sigma}$ set, etc.

The generator consists only of open sets, but the sigma-algebra contains all such classes.